# How to get a range of items from dictionary by specifying start and end index

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of  now

How to get a range of items from dictionary by specifying start and end index in c#

Basically i have to implement paging for my dictionary elements as to show 5 elements then on click next i will show next 5 items and so on

Comment: What `type` of Dictionary?

Comment: You know a dictionary is unordered right?

Comment: are this values in dictionary are integer ??

Comment: @haim770  dictionay is of  <string, myCustomType>

Comment: How do you define a 'range' in a keys of `string`, then?

Comment: i have updated the problem statement to explain more

Comment: Still, how are you going to define what are these 'next 5 elements', when your keys is `string`, and your dictionary is not `Ordered`.

Comment: that's the problem i want to show it like initially first 5 then next 5 elements which are present in dictionary

Comment: @user2754036: What you're attempting is inherently a bad idea, because dictionaries aren't ordered. Paging should be applied to an *ordered* sequence of elements.

Comment: Then @C.Evenhuis and Jon Skeet already gave you the answer.

Comment: @Rishi How you bind Data? you can bind it after order by key, on page index changing you can select item again after order the dictionary by key

Comment: @JonSkeet  do i really need it to be ordered.

Comment: @Rishi: Yes, because otherwise "the first 5 items" makes no sense. If you're only building the dictionary once, just convert it to a list - at which point the order will be stable, of course. If you're actually fetching the data in multiple requests (one for each page) then you need to consider that there's no guarantee that two dictionaries with the same data will give them in the same order.

Comment: @JonSkeet great !! ok will replace my dict with IList and try.

Answer (score 7):

Dictionaries aren't ordered, You can order your dictionary and then select the items between start and end index like below

```
public Dictionary<string, myCustomType> GetData(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return dictionary.OrderBy(d => d.Key).Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex-startIndex +1).ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, v=>v.Value);
}
```

Without all above ordering you can use `SortedList<string, myCustomType>` instead of `Dictionary<string, myCustomType>` and it is sorted and you can select items by index.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dictionary` class is not ordered, you could use `OrderedDictionary` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the range of dictionary by using the below code :

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in MyDic)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```